# How can I make distance of both column short(narrow) in Ant design chart?

Tags: charts, antd

I think gap of both column chart in a group is so big.
Is there any way to make it narrow ?
I couldn't find in those:
https://ant-design-charts.antgroup.com/en/api/plots/common/theme
https://ant-design-charts.antgroup.com/en/api/graphic-style

[image]

thank you